# characteristic polynomial problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and consider the linear map $L_A : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ defined as $L_A(X) = AX$. Show that the characteristic polynomial  $p(L_A(\lambda)) = (p(A(\lambda))^n$.

So I have no idea how to prove this. I know that

$p(L_A(\lambda)) = \det (AX - \lambda I)$

and

$p(A(\lambda)) = \det (A - \lambda I)$

But how can I connect this two informations... Can someone give a hint please?

Thanks!!

NOTE: I posted this a few minutes ago and i was answered but I accidentally deleted the question. Sorry!!

Comment: $p(L_A (\lambda))$ is not what you say it is. Note it must yield a polynomial of degree $n^2$.

Comment: On the "note," why not just undelete it? If you do not find it, go to http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes and follow the relevant link, then undelete.

Comment: nothing appears :/ It's not what I say it is?  I'm not getting, then what is it?

Comment: Second try: go to http://math.stackexchange.com/users/276661/watsonholmes?tab=questions and click recent deleted questions and the end